# Updating entry widget live tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two entry widgets, side by side, when entering a piece of text into one, I want the other the update with the SAME text.

Comment: That seems like a rather strange design, but giving both Entries a `textvariable=` option referring to the same `StringVar` would accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

If you associate an instance of `StringVar` with an entry, that instance and the widget will always be in sync -- a change to either is immediately reflected in another.

A side effect of this is that if two or more widgets share the same instance of `StringVar`, the widgets will also be in sync.

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)

e1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
e2.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```